# Is IONIC 5 stable to start a mobile application?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Am confused to start a project in ionic on which version?

Before answering this please check date of the question asked.I dont want to make it a long tread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-released-january-2019-now-we-have-ionic-5/165130/4) and [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-this-update-safe/165136/5):

> The 5.0.0 is only for the CLI commands, NOT the framework itself. Ionic team gives you commands like start and generate which are wrappers on the angular CLI commands. This update doesn’t not affect your apps

The update should not affect your mobile app building.

**UPDATE 04/2020**

Version 5 of the ionic framework has been released. You can find all the information regarding the new version [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-5/) and [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/support).

Comment: I would love to see an update on your answer now that Ionic 5 is out.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic version `5.0.0-beta.1` still, in the Pre-release stage, I think they planned to release this version at the beginning of the new year.
you can read more about ionic releases and versions in their repo [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases)